# A custom control extending PlaceHolder is marked as ParseChildren(true). Localization does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have a a custom control declared as

```
 [SupportsEventValidation, DefaultEvent("ActiveTabChanged")]
    [ParseChildren(true)]
    [PersistChildren(false)]
    [ToolboxBitmap(typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel))]
    public class TabContainer : System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder, INamingContainer, IPostBackDataHandler, IPostBackEventHandler
    {
```

when I use this in my code markup, I use it as

```
 <MDSL:TabContainer runat="server" ID="t1">
        <ClientEvents>
            <TabChange EventHandler="onTabChanged" />
            <Load EventHandler="onTabLoaded" />
        </ClientEvents>
        <Tabs>
            <MDSL:Tab ID="tablInvoice" runat="server" HeaderText="Invoice">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <MDSL:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="in new tab"></MDSL:TextBox>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </MDSL:Tab>
            <MDSL:Tab ID="tabTzhirdTab" runat="server" HeaderText="My new Shiny Header Text">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <MDSL:Label ID="lbldNew" runat="server" Text="Woohhoo!!" DataField="" DataFormatString=""
                        meta:resourcekey="lbldNewResource5"></MDSL:Label>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </MDSL:Tab>
        </Tabs>
    </MDSL:TabContainer>
```

Everything works fine as I would expect it to. However if I go to design view and do a "Tools -> Generate Local Resources" then pretty much nothing happens :( If I however mark this as

ParseChildren(false)

then the meta tags appears and everything happens as I would expect it to happen. Can anyone help me here?

Thanks!
Nik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. It was the way I was handling the override of `CreateControlCollection()` method. I needed some special handling of this method in the design view. Then I also needed to use the `DesignerSerializationVisibility` attribute correctly on a few public properties of the control.